# Mapbox map not rendering correctly on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mapbox

On page load, I am only getting a partial rendering of my Mapbox map.  If you change the width of the browser or inspect the page the map seems to snap into place and render correctly. I was able to reproduce this issue in JSFiddle [My_Mapbox_Map](http://jsfiddle.net/Vq6KD/143/).  I have tried adding the following code after all the map logic is complete.

```
`setTimeout(function() { map.invalidateSize(); }, 200);`
```

This works well in the JSFiddle, but in my application it works at best 50% of the time, and never works on FireFox. Refreshing the screen multiple times will eventually cause the map to only partially render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if the timeout is not long enough? If you wait until the map is ready to set the view, you will not have that concern. See referenced code and jsfiddle example below.

```
map.whenReady(function()  {
  map.setView([39.53818, -79.43430000000001], 7);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/matttyxm/88onpp6a/

Comment: This approach so far seems to work in my application. Thank you @MattTYXM for the solution. BAAAAAAAAM!

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping by `$timeout` with 0 second worked for me. Confirmed in Firefox too.

```
$timeout(function(){
    map.setView([39.53818, -79.43430000000001], 7);
},0);
```

Comment: I had to refactor some code because my setView was being called early on in a service. This only worked in my app after adding map.invalidateSize(). The idea of putting the map.setView() in the $timeout is a great call!